# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'AND ( )' to data type int

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to send part of my `Where` condition which is located in my stored procedure from C#, so this is how I did it and how it looks:

In fact I needed to get values from checkboxes that user selected and tried to provide them to where condition on my sql, so this is how I did it :

```
foreach (ListItem item in checkBoxUloge.Items)
{
          if (item.Selected)
          {

           command += "T4.RoleID = " + item.Value + " " + "OR" + " " ;

          }

}
var result = command.Substring(command.Length - 3);
if (result.Contains("OR"))
{
     command =  command.Substring(0,command.Length - 3);
}

string sqlCommand = "AND " + "(" + command + ")";
```

And here is my stored procedure which is causing error:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE esp_PlayersGetByRoles
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @SeasonID int,
        @ClubID int,
        @sqlCommand nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN

    Select T1.PlayerID,T1.LicenceNumber,T1.IDNum,T1.ClubID,T1.LastName,T1.FirstName,T2.Title,T1.Date,T3.Year,
    T5.Title as RoleName
    From  Igraci as T1 JOIN Users as T2 ON T1.ClubID=T2.UserID 
                       JOIN Seasons as T3 ON T1.SeasonID=T3.SeasonID 
                       JOIN UsersUloge as T4 ON T1.PlayerID=T4.UserID 
                       JOIN Uloge as T5 ON T4.RoleID=T5.RoleID
    Where T1.ClubID = @ClubID AND T1.SeasonID = @SeasonID + @sqlCommand AND T1.Deleted = 0
    END
    GO
```

I thought string I provided as parameter will fit nicely there so it might look like this:

```
Where T1.ClubID = @ClubID AND T1.SeasonID = @SeasonID + AND (T4.RoleID = 1 OR T4.RoleID = 2 ) AND T1.Deleted = 0
```

because instead of sqlCommand there would be written : `AND (T4.RoleID = 1 OR T4.RoleID = 2 )` as it writes in my code

Comment: No - just no. You are making a fundamental mistake. Your application code is now required to "know" about the query that your procedure is to execute.   And it should not need to know that. Erland has written extensively about this in his [blog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) - read and learn how to do this properly. Your current path is only creating future problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you're missing the @ sign when you're building the WHERE clause.

However, you cannot build the where clause on the fly like that in SQL, unless you execute it as [dynamic-SQL](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/).  It will try to concatenate the @SezonaID value with the string value containted in @sqlCommand, then check if the T1.SezonaID is equal.

So, you'll need to either execute your code as dynamic SQL or build the full SQL string in your application then execute it.  Either way, you'll need to look out for [SQL injection](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/raulga/2007/01/04/dynamic-sql-sql-injection/).

Answer (score 1):

TSQL can't do that, instead, you can use sqlexec to interpret on the fly a dynimic code :

SQLEXE compile and execute an sql code "on the fly".

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE esp_PlayersGetByRoles
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
            @SezonaID int,
            @KlubID int,
            @sqlCommand nvarchar(200)
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
    SET @sql = 'Select T1.IgracID,T1.BrojIskaznice,T1.JMBG,T1.KlubID,T1.Prezime,T1.Ime,T2.Naziv,T1.DatumZapisa,T3.Godina,
        T5.Naziv as Uloga
        From  Igraci as T1 JOIN Korisnici as T2 ON T1.KlubID=T2.KorisnikID 
                           JOIN Sezone as T3 ON T1.SezonaID=T3.SezonaID 
                           JOIN KorisniciUloge as T4 ON T1.IgracID=T4.KorisnikID 
                           JOIN Uloge as T5 ON T4.UlogaID=T5.UlogaID
        Where T1.KlubID = #KlubIDflag# AND T1.SezonaID = #SezonaIDflag# + ''#sqlCommandflag#'' AND T1.Obrisano = 0'

-- Replace flags by variables.
SET @sql = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@sql,'#KlubIDflag#',@KlubID),'#SezonaIDflag#',@SezonaID),'#sqlCommandflag#',@sqlCommand)

-- Execute the final sql code.
EXEC sp_sqlexec @sql

END
```

What is done :
- sql query is placed in a variable as text with flags for parameters.
- Parameters are injected in the code (text parameter must be between ', '+' is the escape caracter that can inject '.
- the whole code is executed.

Comment: still exactlly the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE esp_PlayersGetByRoles
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @SezonaID int,
    @KlubID int,
    @sqlCommand nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
declare @query nvarchar(500);
SET @query='Select T1.IgracID,T1.BrojIskaznice,T1.JMBG,T1.KlubID,T1.Prezime,T1.Ime,T2.Naziv,T1.DatumZapisa,T3.Godina,
T5.Naziv as Uloga
From  Igraci as T1 JOIN Korisnici as T2 ON T1.KlubID=T2.KorisnikID 
                   JOIN Sezone as T3 ON T1.SezonaID=T3.SezonaID 
                   JOIN KorisniciUloge as T4 ON T1.IgracID=T4.KorisnikID 
                   JOIN Uloge as T5 ON T4.UlogaID=T5.UlogaID
Where T1.KlubID ='+ @KlubID+' AND T1.SezonaID ='+ @SezonaID +' '+ @sqlCommand+' AND T1.Obrisano = 0'
EXEC sp_sqlexec @query;
END
GO
```